# Xamarin Android Support Library custom Styles

Tags: android, xamarin, android-support-library

I have an Android Application (Xamarin/Visual Studio) with the `Minimum Android Version: 2.3 (API Level 10 - Gingerbread)` and `Compile Android Version: 6.0 (Marshmallow)`.

I try to support all these Android Versions while keeping the Material Design Look of my App.

I tried using the Support Libraries (from NuGet: `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` version `23`, and `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView` version `23`), and added them to my Project.

Now, I created 3 custom styles for CardViews; in my Resources/values/styles.xml, I have the following Code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <resources>
    <!--A single normal lesson for the Timegrid-->
    <style name="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.Lesson">
      <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/orange_500</item>
      <item name="cardCornerRadius">18dp</item>
    </style>

    <!--A single newly added lesson for the Timegrid-->
    <style name="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.LessonNew">
      <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/green_500</item>
      <item name="cardCornerRadius">18dp</item>
    </style>

    <!--A single cancelled lesson for the Timegrid-->
    <style name="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.LessonCancellation">
      <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/grey_500</item>
      <item name="cardCornerRadius">18dp</item>
    </style>

  </resources>
```

I cannot compile, because of the following Error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView'.
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the style parent to `CardView` and change your `Name` to a non-dot-qualified (local) name.

#### Style Example:

```
<style name="LessonNew" parent="CardView">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">18dp</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I still get this error: ```Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'CardView'.```

Comment: Do I need to add [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat) or [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView) Support Lib?

Comment: `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView`

Comment: Nothing else? I only have the v7.CardView added from NuGet and I still get the Error that CardView can't be found.

Comment: @MarcR. Thats is it for cardview... can you assign those properties (i.e. `cardElevation`) directly on a `CardView` instead of using a style? And the project/application compiles and runs properly? If so, not an issue with the Java cardview support lib.

Comment: No, it can't find CardView anywhere.. It does not compile with CardView Tags. [I uploaded my Project to Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3Lo8JC96lLfU0JVVm1qUVJKY3M) if you have the time to take a quick look... Thanks

Comment: @MarcR. It worked fine once I changed the "Name" and "Parent" to what is in my answer as what you uploaded was still the incorrect version. ( You also have have no `CardView` elements in your layout... you might want to work on that first before trying to create styles for something that does not exist... )

Comment: My bad, I forgot to push my local version. I downloaded the zip aswell now and changed to name & parent, but it didn't work... Has to be something with my PC, I'll install all needed tools once I get home, hopefully I find a list which conntains all what I need. Thank you!

Comment: What files did you exactly change? I only changed the Name and Parent Tags from the .zip, and when I compile I get [these errors..](http://i.imgur.com/RCqEX0q.png)

Comment: Now I get [these errors](http://i.imgur.com/Ba8XAbK.png).. Why is xamarin/android so strange